# Stylus not parsing some directives

Tags: node.js, stylus, jeet-grid

Using the Stylus / Jeet's `column()` or `col()` mixins, some are not compiling, but showing up literally in my generated css files. This should not be happening.

### Test.styl

```
@import 'jeet'

#main
    center(1000px)

#content
    col(2/3)

#sidebar
    col(1/3)
```

### Generated test.css snippet

```
#content,
col(2/3), //<- This shouldn't be here
#sidebar {
   ...
}
#content:before,
col(2/3):before, //<- or this
#sidebar:before,
#content:after,
col(2/3):after, //<- this too
#sidebar:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Repeat after me: Don't mix tabs and spaces for indenting.

Looking at non-printable chars in my `.styl` file led me to the problem:

```
#main
{\t}center(1000px)

#content
{\b\b\b\b}col(2/3)

#sidebar
{\t}col(1/3)
```

Stylus was correctly parsing the majority case (tabs) and not parsing the edge case (spaces).